# Как поменять фон?

Tags: css

Как мне поменять фон 2-й страницы в CSS? Используется фон 1-й страницы?

Answer (score 1):

OMG...
Для первой страницы:

```
<body style='background-image: url(page1Bg.jpg)'> <!--page1Bg.jpg - имя файла фона первой страницы-->
```

Для второй страницы:

```
<body style='background-image: url(page2Bg.jpg)'> <!--page2Bg.jpg - имя файла фона второй страницы-->
```

P.S. товарищи профи, тапками не швыряйтесь, подозреваю, что тут тяжелый случай.

Answer (score 0):

Подключите другой css-файл/перепишите тег style/укажите background-image в body - вариантов масса. Как делаете вы?